# Open custom page from within section?

Tags: nsis

I am putting together my first NSIS installer script, and having some trouble.

I am using Modern UI and have provided a simplified script below:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
Page custom CustomPage

Section "Tomcat" SEC01  
;stuff in here to install Tomcat from bundled installer  
SectionEnd

Section "Deploy WARS" SEC02  
;Fire a separate custom page so that I can use nsDialog to get
;user to choose a folder location for deploying WARs.
;(as potentially their could be more than one Tomcat installed) 
SectionEnd
```

From what I have read, you cannot fire a custom page from within a section.
**So how can I maintain the MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS page to allows user to choose on if they want to install Tomcat AND/OR also deploy WARs.**

I will def need a custom page right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than one instfiles page so you could have a installer with this page order:

1. Components
2. InstFiles (Installs Tomcat)
3. Directory (Choose WAR destination)
4. InstFiles (Install WAR)

```
Section "Tomcat" SECTOM
SectionEnd
Section /o "WAR" SECWAR
SectionEnd
Section
;Use macros from sections.nsh to deselect SECTOM and select SECWAR
SectionEnd
```

The pre callback functions for page 3 and 4 need to use SectionFlagIsSet from sections.nsh and call `Abort` if the War component was not selected so the pages are skipped.

---

Another alternative is to try the [DlgHost](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/DlgHost_plug-in) plugin and show the custom dialog in a child window on your instfiles page...

Comment: ahh - ok.  any chance u could elaborate on the SectionFlagIsSet bit?

Comment: Should I be calling SectionFlagIsSet between the SECTOM section and the SECWAR section as opposed to at the end? IM a bit confused on the ordering

Comment: I don't really understand the logic you are after, maybe something like http://pastebin.com/QqtjXEg1?